# Asynchronously decompress a gzip file

Tags: f#

As a F# training, I'm trying to decompress a gzip file. Here is the code I wrote :

```
let decompress (inputStream: Stream) (outputStream : Stream) = async {
    use gs = new GZipStream(inputStream, CompressionMode.Decompress)
    let buffer = Array.zeroCreate<byte> 4096

    let rec decompressInternal() = async {
        let! read = gs.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) |> Async.AwaitTask
        match read with
        | 0 ->
            inputStream.Dispose()
            return ()
        | _ ->
            do! outputStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, read) |> Async.AwaitTask |> Async.Ignore
            return! decompressInternal()
    }

    return! decompressInternal()
}
```

I also wrote a unit test, which fails for the moment (I get an empty string, as if the assertion occurs after the decompress operation) :

```
[<Fact>]
let ``Decompress a gzipped file`` () =
    use fs = new FileStream("Input/test.txt.gz", FileMode.Open)
    use ms = new MemoryStream()
    decompress fs ms |> Async.RunSynchronously
    use sr = new StreamReader(ms)
    Assert.Equal ("This is a test", sr.ReadToEnd())
```

I think I misued one of the F# async capablibilites, but I cannot see my mistake...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your use of Async is perfectly fine. You just have a `MemoryStream` whose position is still after the write, so there is nothing to read from there. Use the following before creating the `StreamReader` to reset the position and it will work:

```
ms.Seek(0L, SeekOrigin.Begin) |> ignore
```